# How to declare winposget object within visual basic

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, autoit

I have attempted to use an autoit object WinGetPos to handle a popup within a thread in a vb project, I would like WinGetPos function to return the x and y coordiantes of the specified popup and have used the below code, having first imported the AutoItX3.PowerShell.dll reference to my project. I am unable to generate any array could anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

```
Imports AutoIt
Imports AutoItX3Lib

Private Declare Auto Function WinGetPos Lib "AutoItX3.PowerShell.dll" (ByVal mywindowtitle As String) As Array

Public Sub Main()
    Dim PopUpThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf PopUpHandler)

    With PopUpThread 'thread is looking for PopUp and press OK
        .IsBackground = True
        .Start()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub PopUpHandler()
    Dim Ret As Integer
    Dim myarray As Array

    Do
        Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose File to Upload")
        If Ret <> 0 Then
            myarray = WinGetPos("Choose File to Upload")
            MsgBox(UBound(myarray))
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoItX is a well known and documented Programm. So why don't just look into the help file. There you will find how to use and WinGetPosX, WinGetPosY, WinGetPosHeight and WinGetPosWidth, but **no WinGetPos**. That may be the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have consulted the help file extensively to no avail :( The WinGetPos function should return an array consisting of WinGetPosX, WinGetPosY, WinGetPosHeight and WinGetPosWidth. My issue however is that whatever code I try I cannot get my vb.net project within visual studio to recognise the function and am getting a "wingetpos is not declared error", can anyone possibly provide an example of a working piece of code containing this function? many thanks

Comment: Perhaps someone can take over. I'm on a bicycle tour for one week.

Comment: You read the wrong documentation. WinGetPos is a function you can only use in AutoIt itself. You work with the active X component of AutoIt, called AutoItX. So you can only work with the function I stated above.